# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Selection' of undefined

Tags: list, javascript, permissions

I have a button that runs a JS function (in a Script Editor Web Part):

```
function flexRegistration() {

    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    ...
```

However if I am not logged in, I get an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Selection' of undefined`

How can I get this to run for anonymous users, or for a specific permissions level? (owners, Members, Visitors, or other)?

Here's the actual page:
http://www.sd72.bc.ca/school/timberline/Programs/Flex/Pages/default.aspx

The button that triggers the function is there called "Register for Selected Events"

The list being read is the same one that is on display and is publicly readable (filter to Dec 16th to get events, though not necessary to see error)

Comment: I think you should turn on the Allow Anonymous User on your site.

Comment: Anonymous users can view.

Comment: I found there is person meet the same trouble with you. Can you view this link [Access ribbon](http://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2013/05/10/visitors-cant-access-ribbon-for-publishing-pages-in-sharepoint-2013/) ? I guess your permission need at least `Manage Personal Views` permission.

Comment: One more thing, your function `flexRegistration` will count items of both of Event list and  Documents for Parents list. You should have condition if selected list is Event list or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the JS library isn't loading for anonymous users, so ListOperation doesn't exist.

It can be loaded like this:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.Core.js', 'SP.ListOperation', function () { 
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    ...
});
```

This resolved the error